# Downloading PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, file-put-contents

```
$ext = pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if ( $ext == 'pdf' || $ext == 'doc' || $ext == 'docx') {
  file_put_contents('product-docs/'.$slug.'-'.$r.'.'.$ext, $url);
}
```

I'm expecting this code to download the document, instead it saves the file with the right extension, but opening it in editor shows that the content of the file is the URL itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
if ( $ext == 'pdf' || $ext == 'doc' || $ext == 'docx') {
  $doc = file_get_contents($url);
  file_put_contents('product-docs/'.$slug.'-'.$r.'.'.$ext, $doc);
}
```

Comment: If looking to push files to the webclient, you might want to look at XSendFile apache mod. The problem with the `file_get_contents` method is memory consumption is exponential so the site can't handle a large load.  Try something like this library :  https://github.com/microvb/Protected-Signed-URLs-Self-Hosted    to build secure urls